# Regex return sucess if there is none of the keywords

Tags: regex

I have three text file

File 1 : AAA BBB CCC DDD EEEE

File 2 : AAA BBB CCC DDD FFFF

File 3 : AAA BBB CCC DDD

I'm searching a regex that return sucess on "File 3" because it doesn't contain "EEEE" and "FFFF"

i trying this kind (whithout success), it match if suffix "EEEE" or "FFFF" is absent

```
(?!EEEE|FFFF)
```

I search more and i find the exact regex that match, I want to reverse this regex :

```
(.*?EEEE.*?|.*?FFFF.*?)
```

Any suggestions ?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Most languages have a .Contains() function, why not use that?

Comment: it's pure regex (no specific language) use in Expresso software. In fact, the program load regex in config files to recognize file format. It work in 90% cases but i don't find the semantic for test the absence of words. I cannot modify the program to include a contains() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution with Multiline option activated

```
^(?!.*EEEE.*|.*FFFF.*).*?$
```

Explanation :

> **^** : begin string
>
> **(?!)** : Match if suffix is absent
>
> **.*EEEE.*|.*FFFF.*** : the suffix excluded are selected from 2 alternatives *any character EEEE or FFFF followed by any character*
>
> **.*?** : any character, any repetition as few as possible
>
> **$** : end line or string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what all your data looks like, but try ^((?!EEEE|FFFF).)*$

Comment: This works on the examples you provided with python's re.match

Comment: Neat when I use 
re.match('^((?!EEEE|FFFF).)*$', 'File 1: AAA BBB CCC DDD') 
in python it returns a match for me. And doesn't if I add EEEE or FFFF at the end of the string.